# File upload in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-upload

I have one application in which there is an option for file upload.

For file upload, UI is coming for that, we can select the file. After that ideally, it has to store in a folder that is generated dynamically based on the application session id.

Problem: Uploaded File not coming to that particular folder.

How can I access a file from JSON in the below format using python?

File uploaded is already encoded like below

'messageobj': {'fileData': 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD...........

Upon receiving the encoded file , I have to decode it to base64

Please help

Comment: Not quite sure what it is you want.

Comment: how to access file  in following json format            "messageobj":{
      "refmsgid":"imgupload",
      "text":"imgupload",
      "type":"file",
      "referralParam":"None",
      "fileData":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ }

Comment: So, decode filedata and put the contents into a python file object would do the trick right?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.